# How does Apple know if an App is Uninstalled

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store

Does Apple get notified when a user uninstalls an app? I'm asking since I know Apple uses retention amount to rank an app in its algorithm, but does it really know when an app is uninstalled? Or does it simply just assume an app is uninstalled when there is no retention sent for a timeframe?

Asking this in the background of ASO, to better understand how Apple evaluates apps.

Comment: What's your need?? Do you want to know that user have uninstalled your app?